# Converter String em Calendar

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo

Estou tentando fazer uma conversão de `String` para `Calendar` mas sem sucesso.

Minha String é no formato dd/MM/yyyy.
Preciso converter para yyyy-MM-dd
E setar em um objeto do tipo `Calendar`.
 `void setDATAFUNDACAO(java.util.Calendar value);`

Aqui meu código atual:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse("07/04/2016");
Calendar cal =  sdf.getCalendar();
```

Mas infelizmente ele lança essa `exception`

> Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
>   "07/04/2016" at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337) at
>   teste.main(teste.java:54)

Answer (score 4):

Se você configurou o `SimpleDateFormat` para "yyyy-MM-dd", é este o formato que você deve utilizar no comando `parse`:

```
Date date = sdf.parse("2016-07-04");
```

Esse é o motivo da `exception`.
O código abaixo funcionou pra mim:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse("07/04/2016");
Calendar cal =  sdf.getCalendar();

cal.setTime(date);

String df = sdf2.format(date);

System.out.println(cal.getTime());

System.out.println(df);
```

Comment: Vou testar aqui. Pela manha. Vlw